# UIScrollView recursion

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

In the `UIScrollViewDelegate` `scrollViewDidScroll(UIScrollView)` function, if you change the frame of the delegate's `UIScrollView`, then `scrollViewDidScroll(UIScrollView)` gets called again. A common example of this is when you have a header that shrinks as the user scrolls up and expands as the user scrolls down.

Aside from an implementation in which you unset and reset the scrollView's delegate property like below, are there any ways to prevent recursion? The UIScrollView object has `isTracking` and `isDragging` properties that overlap, and also remain true in the below example.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let d = scrollView.delegate // Prevent recursion by setting the 
    scrollView.delegate = nil

    // Do stuff
    if someCondition == true {
        scrollView.contentOffset = somePoint
        scrollView.frame = someRect
    }

    scrollView.delegate = d // Restore the scrollView's delegate
}
```

NOTE: I DO NOT NEED A TUTORIAL FOR MAKING A COLLAPSIBLE HEADER, NOR DO I NEED A SIMPLE IF CHECK. I'm only specifically asking what options are available for breaking out of scrolling events based on their origin. For example, you could put this at the start of `scrollViewDidScroll`:

```
if(!scrollView.isTracking && !scrollView.isDragging) {
    // Break out if we got here through anything but a touch event
    return
}
```

Comment: What do you eventually want to implement?

Comment: Are you sure that setting `contentOffset` results in the delegate being called? The delegate should only be called when the user scrolls the scroll view.

Comment: @Ryan The specific implementation doesn't matter. I have what I want working, but it seems inelegant to have to unset/reset the delegate to prevent recursion. I want to know if there is a better way.

Comment: @rmaddy yes, try it yourself

Comment: The answer to your question really depends on the specifics of “someCondition” and “somePoint”.

Comment: changing `contentOffset` doesn't make delegate method get called. The reason it is get called is because you are dragging not because you are setting `contentOffset`. To clarify, you can make a button to change `contentOffset`.

Answer (score -1):

I just tried it, and setting `.contentOffset` does **not** cause recursion.

As you drag the content, the delegate receives continuous `scrollViewDidScroll` messages... when you call:

```
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
```

you are still dragging, and the content keeps getting reset to 0,0.

Change your function to this:

```
var i = 0

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    i += 1
    print("did scroll", i)
    scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero
}
```

and you will see it stops counting when you stop dragging - so it is not recursive.

Perhaps you really want to use `scrollViewDidEndDragging` or `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`?

**Edit:**

Perhaps this will work better for you. Keep in mind, as long as you continue to drag inside the scroll view, `scrollViewDidScroll()` will continue to be called.

```
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    print("did end dragging", scrollView.contentOffset)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    print("did scroll", scrollView.contentOffset)
    scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: false)
}
```

If you look at the console output, you should never see more than 2 print()s after you "stop dragging".

Comment: Your function wouldn't cause recursion because of your safety check. Remove it, and set contentOffset to some nonzero value.

Comment: Just did so... same result.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the question because I gave sample code that was too simple. I'll make an edit.

Comment: Check edited answer... might do the job. Haven't tried changing the frame though (maybe a better description of what you're trying to do?).